# How to get notified while a record id is generated in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

1. A user sends a notification to an administrator while he is inserting a new record to any one object.
2. The notification must include the record id.

Comment: welcome to sfse jayagan, did you already try something ? Have a look at workflows.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you need this for every object or only one or two?

Comment: for every object

Comment: Why? Your administrator is going to get a lot of emails this way. If they interested in every object can't they just go and look at them on the system instead of receiving an email?

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard functionality in salesforce that will let you create generic workflow or trigger which will work on ANY object. I believe you need to create a workflow and an email notification action specifically for each of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow on that object and send the Email containg the RecordId on creation of record.